# How do I pass a command parameter in a variable holding the command?

Tags: bash, variables, command-line-arguments

I want to produce the same output as this:

```
bash utilities.bash "is_net_connected"
```

But I don't know how to pass "is_net_connected" if command and file is stored in a variable like this:

```
T=$(bash utilities.bash)
```

I've tried these but it doesn't seem to work. It's not picking up `${1}` in utilities.bash.

```
$(T) "is_net_connected"
$(T "is_net_connected")
```

Not the best way to inport but I'm trying to avoid cluttering my main script with function blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T=$(bash utilities.bash)` doesn't save the command; it *runs* the command and saves its output. You want to define a function instead.

```
T () {
    bash utilities.bash "$@"
}

# Or on one line,
# T () { bash utilities.bash "$@"; }
```

Now

```
T "is_net_connected"
```

will run `bash utilities.bash` with whatever arguments were passed to `T`. In a case like this, an alias would work the same: `alias T='bash utilities.bash'`. However, any changes to what `T` should do will probably require switching from an alias to a function anyway, so you may as well use the function to start. (Plus, you would have to explicitly enable alias expansion in your script.)

---

You might be tempted to use

```
T="bash utilities.bash"

$T is_net_connected
```

**Don't be.** Unquoted parameter expansions are bad practice that only work in select situations, and you *will* get bitten eventually if you try to use them with more complicated commands. Use a function; that's why the language supports them.